# Question about Unit Circle and Trig

Tags: trigonometry

I'm wondering about the difference between $-45 ^{\circ}$ and $315 ^{\circ}$. As I'm reading about it and it doesn't make sense to me if they both land at the same place, there shouldn't be a difference.

But if there isn't a difference then $\frac{7\pi}{4}$ should equal $\frac{-\pi}{4}$ which isn't the case right?
Would really appreciate some clearing up here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Angles that differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$ radians or $360^\circ$ are coterminal angles, meaning that they have the same terminal side.

Comment: The + or - signs are for the (counter-clockwise /  clockwise respectively) directions.

Comment: You answered to yourself already: the point determined on the circle is the same, but there are two different ways of getting there

Comment: @TheMadcap not just two, not for the athletes.

Comment: @King Tut, not being a very good athlete I'm not fond of running around the unit circle :P

Comment: @oijioj yeah, the fact that an angle can be determined by various 'measures' implies both that the trigonometric functions are not injective and (since the measures differ by multiples of $2\pi$) that they are periodic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I the x-y plane both angles describe the same ray line but when we consider the angle as the variable of  a function then $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{7\pi}{4}$ represent two distinct values.

More in general for any angle $\theta$ we have that

- in x-y plane all angles $\theta+2\pi k$ represents the same ray line
- as variable of a function $f(\theta)$, angles $\theta+2\pi k$ represent distinct values

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you.

Comment: @oijioj Well done, You are welcome! Bye

Comment: gimusi. Very nice .Similarly:As  some people like to jog clockwise , others counter clockwise, on the track.;))